# How to calculate $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} (2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-|x|^2/2} dx$ ？

Tags: integration

How to calculate  $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} (2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-|x|^2/2} dx$ ？

In fact, I know it can be written as
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{S^{n-1}~~~(r)}  
(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-r^2/2}    A  dx dr
$$
where $S^{n-1}(r)$ is the $n-1$ dimensional sphere with radius $r$.   The $A$ is an analogue of  Jacobian. I forget what is the $A$ and fail to find a suitable reference.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization).
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}|x|^2\right)\mathrm d^n x=(2\pi)^{n/2}$$

Comment: *Hint.* $$e^{-|x|^2/2}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{-x_k^2/2}.$$ Use this to note that your integral becomes a gaussian integral to the power of $n$.